# excel 2010 how to identify if a word is present in a group of cells or a row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, find, cells

I would like to use a formula to identify if a cell in a group of cell contains a specific word.  Example, I'd like to search if a cell has the content X  The formula's response could be 1 if found, 0 if not found.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`IF` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx) you can do this. Here is the syntax;

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

In a cell you can enter the formula to check a cell for the existence of `X`. If it is there the formula result will be a `1`, else-wise a `0`.

```
=IF(A1="X", 1,0)
```

Here it is in a sheet;

[image]

*Side Note: Sorry for the basic answer, but your question is too vague to give you a more specific details. You might want to read how to [ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question quality.*

Comment: I agree that the question is vague, but it mentions “a group of cell” [sic], which suggests to me that the OP is interested in having a cell that checks a range of cells –– something like `=OR($A1:$A12="X")`, entered as an array formula.  Another ambiguity in the question is the phrase “contains a specific word”.  What if a cell contains “The quick brown fox” and X is “fox”?  Then a simple `=` isn’t good enough; you need to do a `FIND`.

Comment: @scott They also stated "I'd like to search if a cell has the content X" which the above answer is a simple solution for. IMO, without more details it would be unreasonable to read into the question. Feel free to post an answer with a formula using `FIND`. There are more ways than one to get the same results.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I am sorry if I was not clear enough.  I am trying to find if one cell in group of cells has a specific content such as the letter X only (not part of a word like fox).  I hope this is clearer.  JP